# android - why onpreviewframe doesn't work well?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediacodec

I used following code to set a previewcallback

```
   mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
                    if (recording == true) {
                        count++;
                        Log.e("frame","frame number is "+count);
                        if(mThread.isAlive()) {
                            encode(bytes);
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
```

I also added 10 callbackbuffer and for oppening camera I used another thread to increase framerate :

```
  public void newOpenCamera() {
    if (mThread == null) {
        mThread = new CameraHandlerThread();
    }

    synchronized (mThread) {
        mThread.openCamera();
    }
}

private static void oldOpenCamera() {
    try {
        c = Camera.open(1);
        Camera.Parameters parameters = c.getParameters();
        parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
        parameters.setJpegQuality(100);
        parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(parameters.getPreviewFormat())*640*480)/8+1];
            c.addCallbackBuffer(buffer);
        }
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(30);
        parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(30000,30000);
        c.setParameters(parameters);
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.e("camera", "failed to open front camera");
    }
}

public CameraHandlerThread mThread = null;
public static class CameraHandlerThread extends HandlerThread {
    Handler mHandler = null;


    CameraHandlerThread() {
        super("CameraHandlerThread");
        start();
        mHandler = new Handler(getLooper());
    }

    synchronized void notifyCameraOpened() {
        notify();

    }

    public void openCamera() {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                oldOpenCamera();
                notifyCameraOpened();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but there isn't any change in the result. the count of frame in onpreviewframe is about 150 for 15 seconds video. is there any solution to fix number of frame to 30 fps?

Comment: Anything that operates on large frames of data from the camera in software (i.e. `byte[]`) is going to hit a performance limit sooner or later. What are you trying to do?

Comment: encoding bytes and writing in a file.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered that problem about 4 days ago .
I understand your problem is low fps : I have did the following,

Try setting the resolution to 640*480

Comment: my code is a little bit different yet i believe this will do: Log.i(TAG,Chosenresolution: "+mSize.width+" "+mSize.height);
params.setPictureSize(mSize.width, mSize.height);
mCamera.setParameters(params);

Comment: I did it but nothing has changed.

Comment: To have an impact on `onPreviewFrame` you'd want to change the *preview* size rather than the *picture* size.

Comment: I wasn't able to fix the fps with these setting.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices cannot work properly if you fix the fps. You should set a supported fps range instead of fixed value.

Delete:

```
parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(30000, 30000);
```

Maybe you can use the following code:

```
List<int[]> supportedFPSRange = param.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange();
// fps is a range from supportedFPSRange
parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(fps[0], fps[1]);
```